# Making folders according to video names for saving the extracted frames to the specific folder

Tags: python

I have a folder with 3 video files. I want to make different folders as per the video file name to save the extracted frames

I have made a small code which reads the video files and makes the folders as per the video file names. It creates folder of 1st video. But creates folder 2 inside folder 1 and folder 3 inside folder 2. Below is my code

```
def extractFrames(m,n):

    if not os.path.exists:
        os.makedirs(n)

    vid_files=glob(m)
    print(vid_files)


    for v_f in range(len(vid_files)):
        v1=os.path.basename(vid_files[v_f])
        print(v1)
        vid_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
        print(vid_name)
        n = n +'\\video_' + vid_name
        os.makedirs(n)
        print(n)
```

If I have 3 video files namely video1,video2 and video 3 so the code should make 3 folders of video1,video2 and video3 respectively. Currently it makes the 3 folders but folder 2 is made inside folder 1 and folder 3 is made inside folder 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last lines of your code to something like:

```
output = n +'\\video_' + vid_name
os.makedirs(output)
print(output)
```

By writing `n = n + '\\video_' + vid_name` you're always concatenating strings to a same base string. You need to change the variable on the left side so you never change your original value for `n`.

Consider this: in the first loop, `n` will have the string `\\video_` concatenated to it. Then, in the second loop, `n` already has the `\\video_` bit and will now concatenate an extra `\\video_` to it, thus creating a folder within a folder.

Comment: can you please help me out with this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55548775/11312863