# Extract frames from video into specific folder

Tags: python, opencv

I want to extract frames from 3 videos into 3 different folder. Each folder has the frames of their corresponding video file. I am able to access my objective for only the 3rd video. How can I extract the frames for the first 2 videos as well

I have made the folders having names as per the video files till now. Developed the code for frame extraction but can extract only from the last video. Below is my code

```
import cv2
import glob
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil

def extractFrames(m,n):

    if not os.path.exists:
        os.makedirs(n)

    vid_files=glob(m)
    print(vid_files)

    for v_f in range(len(vid_files)):
        v1=os.path.basename(vid_files[v_f])
        print(v1)
        vid_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
        print(vid_name)
        output = n +'\\video_' + vid_name
        os.makedirs(output)
        print(output)





    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_files[v_f])
    print(vidcap)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    seconds = 2
    fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Gets the frames per second
    multiplier = fps * seconds
    count=0

    while success:
        img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
        image_path = output + "/" + img_name
        frameId = int(round(vidcap.get(1)))
        success,image = vidcap.read()
        if frameId % multiplier == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(filename = image_path, img = image)
            count+=1


    vidcap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    print('finished processing video {0} with frames {1}'.format(vid_files[v_f], count))
    return output


x=("C:\\Python36\\videos\\*.mp4")
y=("C:\\Python36\\videos\\videos_new")

z=extractFrames(x,y)
```

If there are 3 videos namely video1,video2,video3. I want to extract the corresponding frames into their specific folders i.e video1 folder,video2 folder, video3 folder. Currently I am able to extract the frames for only the 3rd video into folder video3. How can I do it for video1 and video2 as well

Comment: One thing your missing is the argument in `if not os.path.exists:`. This should specify which directory: `if not os.path.exists(n):`.

Comment: @NielsHenkens I tried this and it looks like this has nothing to do with extracting frames from videos into specific folder. how can I extract videos frames into their corresponding folders. I think it has something to do with Looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation on the part from `vidcap = ...` down is off. Therefor only the last file in the for-loop is used.

```
import cv2
import glob
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil

def extractFrames(m,n):
if not os.path.exists:
        os.makedirs(n)

    vid_files=glob(m)
    print(vid_files)

    for v_f in range(len(vid_files)):
        v1=os.path.basename(vid_files[v_f])
        print(v1)
        vid_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
        print(vid_name)
        output = n +'\\video_' + vid_name
        os.makedirs(output)
        print(output)


        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_files[v_f])
        print(vidcap)
        success,image = vidcap.read()
        seconds = 2
        fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Gets the frames per second
        multiplier = fps * seconds
        count=0

        while success:
            img_name = vid_name + '_f' + str(count) + ".jpg"
            image_path = output + "/" + img_name
            frameId = int(round(vidcap.get(1)))
            success,image = vidcap.read()
            if frameId % multiplier == 0:
                cv2.imwrite(filename = image_path, img = image)
                count+=1

        vidcap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        print('finished processing video {0} with frames {1}'.format(vid_files[v_f], count))
    return output # indent this less

x=("C:\\Python36\\videos\\*.mp4")
y=("C:\\Python36\\videos\\videos_new")

z=extractFrames(x,y)
```

Comment: I had tried this approach earlier as well. This creates the folder and extracts frames for only the 1st video file

Comment: If u try printing the variable vidcap it has only single output. I can't understand how can I read and extract frames from all video files recursively. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My bad, I also added an indent to the `return` statement. Fixed it now in the edit above. Can you try that one?

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for your valuable time and help brother :)